# JQuery: How do I select the nth inputs in each row of a table?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with n columns, and n-2 inputs in each column. I want to iterate over a single column of inputs, but can't figure out how to select them.

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `nth-child()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). For example, to get the third column of inputs:

```
$('#table-id td:nth-child(3) input')
```

Remember that, in accordance with the CSS spec, `nth-child()` is 1-indexed.